# Solve problems using bitcoin smart contracts

Tags: smartcontracts

Been trying to ask this to few people on different platforms but nothing was helpful so trying here and will keep trying because I don't even know what else can I do to learn more and contribute.

What will be the best way or resources to refer if someone has an idea and want to implement it using bitcoin smart contracts?

For example: If I want to create a decentralized insurance product which might even need external data so won't be completely decentralized but trust minimized, non custodial, non kyc and better than present solutions. Users will have to regularly pay some amount which should be locked in some multisig setup and used in a way that it gets interest so maybe provide liquidity in joinmarket, create a lending/borrowing thing using discreet log contracts or something else, these profits can be used to cover life and release amounts after verification on claims

How would I approach solving this problem using bitcoin?

What are best resources to learn more about discreet log contracts, it's examples?

Answer (score 1):

> What will be the best way or resources to refer if someone has an idea and want to implement it using bitcoin smart contracts?

If smart contracts involve the use of external data (oracles) then [Discreet Log Contracts](https://github.com/discreetlogcontracts/dlcspecs/blob/master/Resources.md) are the best possible way.

> How would I approach solving this problem using bitcoin?

I have mentioned few points in this doc, it won't be easy creating an oracle that decides if someone is dead or alive, create incentives around it, use of funds, exception handling etc. however nothing wrong in trying: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1baOWfya2mqd3ZAoDS4a2VQlb3-q4JCILXRN-oe4_zOk/edit

> What are best resources to learn more about discreet log contracts, it's examples?

DLC channel in Lightning Dev Kit slack :https://lightningdevkit.slack.com/

**Examples:**

P2P Derivatives: https://github.com/p2pderivatives/p2pderivatives-client

https://medium.com/crypto-garage/step-by-step-guide-p2p-derivatives-application-c0454606428e

[Benthecarman](https://twitter.com/benthecarman) is working on a project which can be used to experiment with DLC (scala):

https://github.com/benthecarman/krystal-bull

[image: krystal-bull-dlc]

[Nicolas Dorier](https://twitter.com/NicolasDorier) is also working on [NDLC](https://github.com/dgarage/NDLC) and I tried a creating a GUI for NDLC-CLI using C#:

[image: NDLC-GUI]