# Would it be a dilemma to wanting to earn interest if our bitcoin is in some exchange, but we also want the security in our own wallet?

Tags: interest

I think one general thinking is that, for the bitcoin to be secure, it has to be in our own wallet, and preferably, a hardware cold wallet.

But at the same time, we would also see that 3% interest we can earn on our bitcoin gone every year, if the bitcoin is kept in some exchange.

Is there a way to solve this problem currently? But except maybe if there is a insurance system like FDIC insured, so that we can deposit our bitcoin somewhere, have it guarded against theft, and at the same time earning interest?

Comment: Perhaps this related topic answers your question: [Is there logically any way to “live off of Bitcoin interest” without giving up control of your coins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/100935/5406)

Comment: No it does not. Some answers in there are very old too. Is this a "let's try to search and if there is a title that looks like it, then close the question"?

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't answer your question? It looks very applicable to me, and only a few months old.

Comment: @nonopolarity https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/100939/ this has few options mentioned to get interest on your bitcoin in self custodial ways still involving some risks. Insurance for centralized exchange is something a company needs to decide. For decentralized insurance of smart contracts, life, health etc. I had some ideas/concept which is not yet implemented with some code using DLC: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99497/